# Export animation from blender to a threes.js program

Tags: export, three.js

I am trying to export an animation from Blender to a program using Three.js. The animation is  a boolean modifier. I don't know how export it from Blender correctly and after how to insert it in my three js program. I want to export it using the collada format because the .json three js export, doesn't work well, in my program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it 's about a limitation in a destination (three.js) which can not realistically at the moment work with boolean modifiers in an animation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things here:

1. you need help with three.js exporter addon and
2. the thing you are trying to export isn't supported.

The current Three.js exporter will export certain types of animation, but  an animation where the Boolean modifier is of prime importance (modifying the mesh every frame) isn't going to work as you hoped. For that to work Three.js would need to have a way to deal with the boolean operation, and it would need to be analogous to Blender's Boolean modifier. To my knowledge Three.js has no such feature.

The exporter by MrDoob and associates strips out modifiers by applying them if possible. The boolean modifier can't really be applied per frame unless you export the mesh (per frame) to a format that Three.js knows how to handle (per frame). But that turns into a different question, that you might want to ask on github issue tracker of Three.js

Comment: Hello !
Thanks for your answer ! Ok, to find a solution i ask the question in github, i hope it will be possible to do this !